# Neo4j and QueryDSL produces "No property for type at runtime

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-rest, querydsl

Springboot 2 Application using Neo4j 3.3.4 via spring-data-rest JDK8

**The dependences**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>timetree</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.1.51.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
     <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>uuid</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.1.51.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
     <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-lucene4</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**The Entity**

```
@NodeEntity
@QueryEntity
@Data
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    private String uuid;

    @Version
    Long version;

    @LastModifiedDate
    Date date;

    @Labels
    private List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_MEDIA", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Collection<Gallery> mediaList;

}
```

**The repository**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends
        PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {
}
```

**Create Q-Classes**

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <!--<processor>org.springframework.data.neo4j.querydsl.SDNAnnotationProcessor</processor>-->
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

When the repository extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor I get a huge stack trace at app startup with the following among others.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property exists found for type Person!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:356) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:267) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.derived.DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery.<init>(DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery.java:53) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(GraphQueryLookupStrategy.java:58) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.java:66) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 159 common frames omitted
```

What have I done wrong?
Am I using the correct querydsl version? Should I go back to mysema builds? 
Is there a repository for this purpose like in JPA world?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I have the exact same issue

Comment: I don't know about now but at that time 4.2.1 version wasn't fully compatible with 3.3.4. I'm not sure if it had implemented the mandatory features.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Neo4j **does not** support QueryDSL.

Supported repository functionality can be checked in the table [on this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#neo4j-repo-intro)

You will notice that QueryDslPredicateExecutor is not supported.

And [according to Gerrit Meier](https://community.neo4j.com/t/spring-data-neo4j-querydslpredicateexecutor-general-question/5849), there are no plans to implement it in the near future.